# How to make a simple Python Text Server

Tags: python, server, cherrypy

I'm trying to make a webserver that serves string. Yes, that's it, just string, no variables, no CSS. The problem has been the refresh. Assume that the string changes every second, stored in a Python variable. The problem is serving to the client, I want to make it so that the client doesn't have to request the page again, rather, the server sends the new string every time it's updated.

I tried Cherrypy but the method used is a return one, which exits a loop. How can I make this "simple" web server? Really new to sockets programming too.. Just heard the term yesterday..
Edit : I think it should be served by HTML.. I want it to be able to be opened via browsers
Edit: I think the pseudocode should be like this

```
def loopingfunction:
    do things
    return var
def server:
    while True:
         displayed_text=loopingfunction()
         send_displayed_text_to_client()
```

Comment: Always make sure to add the source code that you have used/written and it shall help others understand your question better.

Comment: You might want to look into WebSockets, they are a bidirectional way to actively send data from server to client and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Not a cherrypi implemented solution, but if I got your question right, here's a basic implementation with explanation:

```
import time, socket, sys
 
socket_server = socket.socket()
server_host = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname(server_host)
sport = 8080
 
print('This is your IP address: ',ip)
server_host = input('Enter friend\'s IP address:')
name = input('Enter Friend\'s name: ')
 
 
socket_server.connect((server_host, sport))
 
socket_server.send(name.encode())
server_name = socket_server.recv(1024)
server_name = server_name.decode()
 
print(server_name,' has joined...')
while True:
    message = (socket_server.recv(1024)).decode()
    print(server_name, ":", message)
    message = input("Me : ")
    socket_server.send(message.encode())
```

Firstly, we import the `socket` library because this python library contains the necessary functions to implement sockets. The `sys` library provides the system module which is responsible for providing data related to the system directory, functions, and methods.
The `time` module enables us to perform numerous actions about the conversions and descriptions of time.

The port is assigned as 8080. This port is chosen because this is a default-free port on most machines.

The details of the incoming connection are stored in the client_name variable. The client’s name can be a maximum of 1024 bytes.

The user enters the message. This is encoded using encode() and then sent across through the socket. The message is sent using the send() function which is invoked on the connection object created during the invocation of accept() function earlier. It then displays “message has been sent…”.

The incoming message is received using the recv() of the conn object. It can receive up to 1024 bytes of information. The message is decoded on the server-side using decode()

Comment: Okay, sorry for not adding source, because I'm really confused on how to implement it.. I understand how that works, but that means I have to prepare an application to receive the socket message, right? Sorry, but what I meant is to read the served variable via a browser, maybe via html. But all the implementations I've read is that it uses a [return] block, which means we can't insert a [while True:] because return exits the function..

Answer (score -1):

Solved! Using https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel/tree/master/eel , this is achievable.

Basically, initalize a web server that exposes python functions, and then refresh the page and change the contents using javascript, receiving variables from python.